# Accordion in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, accordion

I'm attempting to build a accordion where all the contacts under each Account drill down like an accordion. I referred [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-accordion-section/example).

```
<template>
<lightning-card  title="Accounts with Contacts">
    <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" >
    <template if:true={accounts}>
        <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
            Account - {account.Name}
            <lightning:accordionSection key={account.id} name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
                <aura:set attribute="body">
                    <template for:each={account.Contacts} for:item="co">
                       <p key={co.Id}> Contact - {co.Name}</p>
                   </template>
                </aura:set>
            </lightning:accordionSection>           

        </template>
   </template>
  </lightning:accordion>
  </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

APEX:

```
public class FetchMultipleRecords {

@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<Account> search() {
return [SELECT Id,Industry, Name ,Type,(SELECT id, Name FROM contacts) FROM 
 Account LIMIT 2];        
}
}
```

My results shows only Accounts without contacts. If I remove the accordion, I get both accounts and contacts together.

Let me know if I'm building it the wrong way.

Comment: this `Account - {account.Name}` should probably be put into the accordion section label. `label="Accordion Title A"` looks like it was copy/pasted from the example.

Comment: Also, I don't think that `aura:set` is valid for the given context. [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_set_intro.htm) You should check out [slots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots). The accordion only has **actions** and **default** slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Aura components in LWC. You'll know you're trying to use an Aura component because it'll have a `:` in it. For example, `lightning:accordion` is an Aura component, while `lightning-accordion` is an LWC component. You'll need to look at the correct [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-accordion/example) to get the correct syntax. The same is also true for `lightning:accordionSection` versus `lightning-accordion-section`.

Comment: I was able to achieve, with the correct documentation